# How do i solve an internal relocation error in arm assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, linker-errors

After i compiled my code i received an error i never heard of before, any help on fixing it ?

```
.data
        array: .word 1
               .word 32
               .word 10
               .word 8
               .word 33
        index: .word 0
        numberFour: .word 4
        length: .word 5
.text
.global main_

main:
        ldr r1, adr_array
     ldr r2, adr_index
        ldr r2, [r2]
        ldr r3, adr_length
        ldr r3, [r3]
        ldr r7, #0
        ldr r11, adr_numberFour
        ldr r11, [r11]
        mov r5, #0

topOfLoop:subs r6, r5, r3
          beq quit
          mul r7, r5, r11
          add r7, r7, r1
          ldr r1, [r7]
 subs r8, r5, #0
          beq add1

secondIfStatement: ldr r8, [r7]
                   sub r9, r7, #4
                   ldr r10, [r9]
                   subs r11, r8, r10
                   bpl add2
                   beq add2
                   str r7, [r10]
                   str r9, [r8]
                   sub r5, r5, #1
                   b topOfLoop

add1: add r5, r5, #1
      b secondIfStatement
add2: add r5, r5, #1
      b topOfLoop
```

The error is `Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up`

It's showing in lines 23, 25, 27, 29, 30

Comment: What is the assembler?  `adr_length` is weird.  It would be `adr r2, index` but that won't work as the label `index` is not in the same section as the PC (code).  You should use `ldr r2,=index`.  This seems to be the syntax you want.  See: [gnu assembler](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html#ARM-Opcodes).

Comment: Please highlight lines 23, 25, 27, 29 and 30. Counting to 30 manually is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: where are the labels adr_* defined?  if too far away then the linker wont be able to generate instructions that can reach.  need to change how you write that code so that those addresses are reachable.